# Convert timestamp in the PDT zone to datetime - Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have timestamps in the following format: `Thu, 11 Jan 2001 06:19:00 -0800 (PST)`.
I've tried applying the `datetime` library with the following format:

`datetime.strptime('Mon, 18 Jun 2001 06:40:30 -0700 (PDT)', '%A, %d %B %Y %HH:%MM:SS %z%Z')`

but it always raised an error:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Mon, 18 Jun 2001 06:40:30 -0700 (PDT)' does not match format '%A, %d %B %Y %HH:%MM:SS %Z'
```

what's the correct format for above timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for the timestamp is:

```
%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z
```

There is a difference between `Mon` and `Monday` => `%a` and `%A`. Same is for `Jun` and `June`.

Comment: ```raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Mon, 18 Jun 2001 06:40:30 -0700 (PDT)' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z %Z'``` ... still getting errors